# Prove that if $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$, $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = \infty$ ...

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove that if $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$, $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = \infty$, then $\lim_{x\to a} [f(x)]^{g(x)} = 0$

NOTE: This shows that $0^\infty$ is not an indeterminate form.

Would this solution be correct?
$$
\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)]^{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}e^{g(x)\ln(f(x))}=0
$$
Because
$$
\lim_{x\to a}[\ln(f(x)]]=\lim_{y\to 0}(\ln y)=-\infty
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to a}[g(x)]=\infty
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{x\to a}[g(x)\ln(f(x)]]=-\infty
$$
Finally
$$
\lim_{x\to a}[e^{g(x)\ln(f(x)}]=0
$$

Comment: Please please please write it using $\LaTeX$...

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Here's the latex form for what you've written (for future use). Replace the "@" signs with dollars to make them get formatted nicely:
Prove that if @f(x) > 0 @ for all @x,@ @\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = 0@ and @\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x) = \infty@, then @\lim_{x\rightarrow a} [f(x)]^{g(x)} = 0@.

When you substitute, you get this:

Prove that if $f(x) > 0 $ for all $x,$ $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x) = \infty$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} [f(x)]^{g(x)} = 0$.

By the way, I doubt your claim that $0^\infty$ is not indeterminate...but that's a separate matter.

Comment: @John for future reference you can typeset the dollar sign by \\$, so you do not need to have someone replace the '@' signs.

Comment: @John: under the assumption $f(x)>0$, I think $0^\infty$ is indeed non-indeterminate.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution looks good to me. Here's another approach - not better, just different.

There exists $\varepsilon_1$ such that $0 < f(x) < 1$ whenever $0 < |x-a| < \varepsilon_1$. There exists $\varepsilon_2$ such that $g(x) > 1$ whenever $0 < |x-a| < \varepsilon_2$. (Both of these are consequences of the limits given in the hypotheses.)

Therefore whenever $0 < |x-a| < \min\{\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2\}$, we have $0 < f(x)^{g(x)} < f(x)^1$.

The desired $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)} = 0$ then follows from $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = 0$ and the squeeze theorem.